# Example of a non-extendable TQFT?

Tags: topological-quantum-field-theory, quantum-topology

All 3D TQFTs I know of are of Reshetikhin-Turaev type. These are fully extended and I wondered if there are known examples of TQFTs such that there is no once-extended TQFT extending it.

Comment: [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/8772/97265) and its answers discuss a nonextendable theory in the 2D case.

Comment: Also, is it true that Reshetikhin-Turaev TQFTs are fully extended? I know they've been extended down to dimension 1, and that it's believed that they can be fully extended to dimension 0, but I wasn't aware of a proof. (Of course, I could just be out of the loop.)

Comment: Depends what you mean, do you want a 3210 theory for *some* delooping of categories, or for *a particular* delooping?

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for the confusion. I was thinking about extenions down to dimenion 1 when I wrote "fully extended". This is missleading.